# onClick property using setAttribute not working

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, frontend

Im new to JavaScript and learning, I tried to create elements only by using `setattributes` and `createElements` but here the `btn.setAttribute('onclick', 'fun()')` is not working, what could be the concern.

```js
function code() {
    let head1 = document.getElementById('head')
    let lab = document.createTextNode('Enter')
    let input1 = document.createElement('input')
    let btn = document.createElement('button');
    let lab1 = document.createTextNode('Enter Button')
    input1.setAttribute('id', 'ind')
    btn.appendChild(lab1)
    btn.setAttribute('id', 'btn11')
    btn.setAttribute.onclick = function() { fun(); };

    head1.appendChild(lab)
    head1.appendChild(input1)
    head1.appendChild(btn)
}


function fun() {
    let head = document.getElementById('hi')
    para = document.createElement('p')
    txt = document.createTextNode('hi')
    para.appendChild(txt)
    head.appendChild(para)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="code()">Enter</button>
<div id="head"></div>
<div id="hi"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

`setAttribute` is a method but you are using that as if it is a property. There is no `onclick` on `setAttribute`.

You can simply use:

```
  btn.onclick = fun();
```

**OR:** If you really want to use `setAttribute()`

```
btn.setAttribute('click', fun());
```

```html
<script>
    function code() {
        let head1 = document.getElementById('head')
        let lab = document.createTextNode('Enter')
        let input1 = document.createElement('input')
        let btn = document.createElement('button');
        let lab1 = document.createTextNode('Enter Button')
        input1.setAttribute('id', 'ind')
        btn.appendChild(lab1)
        btn.setAttribute('id', 'btn11')
        btn.onclick = fun();

        head1.appendChild(lab)
        head1.appendChild(input1)
        head1.appendChild(btn)
    }

    
    function fun() {
        let head = document.getElementById('hi')
        para = document.createElement('p')
        txt = document.createTextNode('hi')
        para.appendChild(txt)
        head.appendChild(para)
    }


</script>
<body>
    <button onclick="code()">Enter</button>
    <div id="head"></div>
    <div id="hi"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: You are invoking `fun()` when `code()` called

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button onclick="code()">Enter</button>
    <div id="head"></div>
    <div id="hi"></div>

    <script>
      function code() {
        let head1 = document.getElementById("head");
        let lab = document.createTextNode("Enter");
        let input1 = document.createElement("input");
        let btn = document.createElement("button");
        let lab1 = document.createTextNode("Enter Button");
        input1.setAttribute("id", "ind");
        btn.appendChild(lab1);
        btn.setAttribute("id", "btn11");
        btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
          fun();
        });

        head1.appendChild(lab);
        head1.appendChild(input1);
        head1.appendChild(btn);
      }

      function fun() {
        let head = document.getElementById("hi");
        para = document.createElement("p");
        txt = document.createTextNode("hi");
        para.appendChild(txt);
        head.appendChild(para);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```